# How do I stop 10 seconds timer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can't seems to be able to stop the timer when it reaches zero. It will just repeat back to the original timing! See my codes below.

What I am trying to achieve is, once timer is 0, it will replace 00:00 with the text "Your time is up".

HTML:

```
<div class="quizTimer right">
<span>Timer:<br /><span id="qTimer"></span></span>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript which I did:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        console.log(display.textContent);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
            clearInterval(timer); // this piece of code didnt stop the timer
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
        var oneMinute = 10 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#qTimer');
        startTimer(oneMinute, display);
};
```

Comment: clearInterval needs the intervalID you are passing something else. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: You need a reference to timer, like var timer = setinterval(function..........., 1000); then clearInterval(timer) will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval()` expects a reference to the interval to be passed.

You're passing `timer`, which is not a reference to the interval - it's an integer from the passed-in function param.

Assign your interval to a variable and reference that when you want to clear it.

```
let foo = setInterval(() => {
    /* code... */
    clearInterval(foo);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to capture the interval id returned by `setInterval()` and use that:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        console.log(display.textContent);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
            clearInterval(id); // uses returned id
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```